# Setting css on the selected column header in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Is there a way to change the background color of an ng-grid header of a column when it is the one being sorted by? I don't see any different classes on that column than the other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can define your own `headerRowTemplate` which would let you use `ng-class`

https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating

Comment: thank you for the help, but I don't know what type of expression to put into an ng-class to set a class based upon the column that is sorted.

Comment: I figured it out, but it took some time, since there are not listed examples of the rowHeaderTemplate.

I found it in the current ng-grid code I am using and added the conditions in there.

var custHeaderRowTemplate = '<div ng-style="{\'z-index\': col.zIndex()}" ng-class="{\'col_select\': col.showSortButtonDown(), \'col_select_up\': col.showSortButtonUp() }" ng-repeat="col in visibleColumns()" class="ngHeaderCell col{{$index}}" ng-header-cell></div>';

Answer (score 0):

I just did same by adding **headerClass**.
Add **headerClass: "your custom class name"** next to the header in your controller.
Then **apply css on your custom header class in ng-grid**.

Here are more classes :
http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/